# Delay in volley request? - Android Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

```
method1();
method2();
if(result1 && result2)
{
        method3();
}
```

Say that `method1()`  just validates if the textboxes are filled and not empty, and `method2()` validates if the values of the textboxes has duplicates in the database.

`result1 and result2` are class boolean variables,

`result1` will be `true` if the textboxes are filled, and `result2` will be `true` if the values has no duplicates, so `method2` has the volley request.

`method3()` is the process where there will be a volley request to insert the values to the table.

What I thought would happen is:

1. `method1()` will execute and `result1` will be true or false depending on the result
2. `method2()` will execute and the volley process contained in this method will affect `result2` and `result2` will be true or false depending on the result
3. `resul1` and `result2` will be tested in the `if` statement if both are `true` and will proceed to `method3()`

instead of that, the volley request in `method2` takes time to or delays to happen and the code proceeds to the `if` statement checking of both `result1` and `result2` before the volley request of `method2()` responds.

Meaning that even if the whole form is valid, due to this happening `result2` will always be false during the `if` statement checking.

This is what I observed.

So now what I did is `method3()` will execute on the `onResponse` block of the volley request in `method2()`, and `method2()` will execute on the end of `method1()`.

But it feels hacky to me and I do not feel comfortable with it, also the delay of everything happening from the press of the button makes me uncomfortable since its too long.

I am just a college student and I just recently learned android and volley and I do not know how to make this better or if there is any alternative, please help me. Also I'm sorry if my explanation sounds stupid. If there is anyway I can improve this process please tell me. Lots of thanks.

Comment: when you get result1 start method2, when you get the result2 check and start method3

Comment: do you mean if(result1){ method2(); if(result2){ method3(); } } ? Because I tried that and that also did not work.

Comment: no, but you haven't posted your correct code so I cannot write you an example how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens in Volley is that the requests are being made asynchronously, executing the callback that you provide once it receives a response. It does not block execution.

To do what you want just with Volley, you would chain the requests together. Meaning you would only execute `method2` in the callback for `method1`, and execute your if statement in the callback for `method2`.

Another approach to this, depending on your use case, could be utilizing a `CountDownLatch`: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

To do this, you would increase the count of the countdown latch for each request you want to wait upon. Then in the response of each method, you would count the latch down. Once the latch count reaches 0, the wait will release, allowing your if statement to be executed.